# Control dynamically the number of members in c++ data structure

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures, c++11, containers

I am currently writing a program that deal with databases.

I can ask for different options and get a variable number of columns.

The problem is that the data will be gigabytes of information and I can't make one structure with all the possible options. I need to be able to create dynamically a structure with only the members I need and nothing else.

I would also like something better than creating a structure for each of the possible cases!

Here are example of tables:

```
smallint(6) - varchar(255) - double - int(11)
smallint(6) - varchar(255) - double - double - double - int(11)
smallint(6) - smallint(6) - varchar(255) - varchar(255) - double - int(11)
```

Is there any ways to create structures with a dynamic number of members in c++ that are as efficient as a normal struct?

[EDIT]

Here is a solution using @Industrial-antidepressant idea. It works but the only problem it seems 4 times slower than a normal struct.

```
#include <windows.h>

class Column
{
public:
    Column(uint64 nOffset, const type_info* pType)
    {
        m_nOffset = nOffset;
        m_pType = pType;
    }

    uint64 m_nOffset;
    const type_info* m_pType;
};


struct UWElement
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void Set(uint64 nColumn, T value)
    {
        if ((*m_pColumnList)[nColumn].m_pType == &typeid(T))
        {
            uint64 nOffset = (*m_pColumnList)[nColumn].m_nOffset;
            *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_pData + nOffset)) = value;
        }
        else
        {
            assert(0);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    T& Get(uint64 nColumn)
    {
        // No type check here to test speed
        uint64 nOffset = (*m_pColumnList)[nColumn].m_nOffset;
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_pData + nOffset);
    }

protected:
    unsigned char* m_pData;
    std::vector<Column>* m_pColumnList;

    friend class UWElementList;
};



class UWElementList
{
public:
    UWElementList()
    {
        m_nEndOffset = 0;
    }

    template<class T>
    void AddType()
    {
        Column column(m_nEndOffset, &typeid(T));
        m_columnlist.push_back(column);
        m_nEndOffset += sizeof(T);
    }

    void CreateElement()
    {
        UWElement element;
        element.m_pData = new unsigned char[m_nEndOffset];
        element.m_pColumnList = &m_columnlist;
        m_elementList.push_back(element);
    }

    UWElement& operator[](int64 nPos)
    {
        return m_elementList[nPos];
    }

private:
    std::vector<Column> m_columnlist;
    uint64 m_nEndOffset;

    std::vector<UWElement> m_elementList;
};


int main()
{
    struct SimilarStruct
    {
        double a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };

    SimilarStruct similar;
    vector<SimilarStruct> similarList;
    similarList.push_back(similar);

    UWElementList list;
    list.AddType<double>();
    list.AddType<int>();
    list.AddType<int>();
    list.CreateElement();

    // Test writing speed
    uint64 nTick = GetTickCount64();
    for(int i=0; i<100*1000*1000; i++)
    {
        //list[0].Set<double>(0,(double)1.1);       //Speed 140ms
        list[0].Get<double>(0) = (double)1.1;   //Speed 109ms
        //similarList[0].a = (double)1.1;           //Speed 31ms
    }
    cout << GetTickCount64() - nTick << endl;

    double d=0;

    // Test reading speed
    nTick = GetTickCount64();
    for(int i=0; i<100*1000*1000; i++)
    {
        d += list[0].Get<double>(0);                //Speed 94ms
        //d += similarList[0].a;                        //Speed 93ms
    }
    cout << GetTickCount64() - nTick;


    return d;
}
```

Any optimisation that can help speed up things?

Comment: What do you need to do with this data once you have it?

Comment: Will data indexed with column number? Then you need a header structure, with start data indexes and you need a memory chunk that holds the column datas and you need templated get and set methods that use the header index and reinterpret_cast the binary data

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant That is the only solution I think could work but I find the need to bring the header structure everywhere where the data is used not so elegant. This solution could also introduce difficult bugs to solve and corrupting the heap

Comment: @VaughnCato I will iterate many times and read all the values of each column as fast as I can.

Comment: How about keeping each column in a vector of the appropriate type?  It might be even more efficient than a vector of structs because of better packing.

Comment: @VaughnCato This is a good idea but I need to be able to sort the data quickly

Comment: I'm not sure why sorting would be especially slow .

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts if you're open to using the [Boost](http://www.boost.org) libraries.

You can try using a two-dimensional array of [`boost::variant<list of possible types>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html). For a dynamic two-dimensional array, you can use [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

According to the documentation, `boost::variant` has an:

> Efficient implementation -- stack-based when possible (see the section
>   called [“"Never-Empty" Guarantee”](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty) for more details).

I have used vectors of `boost::variant` successfully before to represent database rows, but my memory requirements were much more modest than yours. You'll probably have to benchmark this approach to see if it's feasible.

If you use this approach, you might need some way to determine, at runtime, the index of a given database column. If you want to access a column by name, you could use a `std::map` or `boost::unordered_map` to do the mapping between column names and column indices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: boost::variant will not work because each variant objects use 16 bytes witch will more than double the size of my list.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a linklist. You can use the new operator to allocate memory on the fly to each node.

The performance may not be equal to the performance you would get if a pre-defined struct was used, but it offers more control.

If you still  want to create a dynamic structure only, you can use unions inside structures.

More Info: [Dynamic structures in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102789/dynamic-structures-in-c)

Comment: Will the memory allocation cope with having 100 millions objects each having a linklist of 4 to 10 elements?

Comment: Will all the 100 million objects be used at once? I hope not. You have to keep allocating/de-allocating  when needed.

Comment: Yes I do need them all at the same time and that's the problem. I load all of them in bulk at the moment in a fixed data structure and it works well and quick. I can't imagine at the moment how to create a fast dynamic structures.

Comment: I would not recommend linklists if thats the case. Maybe using unions inside structures?